# Vue-router/Vue.js and axios requests (php file downloading instead of executing)

Tags: php, vue.js, axios, vuex

My stack is vue.js/vuex/vue-router/axios. I am trying to do a post request with axios from the store to a local php file.

However when I try to go to the php file url directly, it is simply downloading and not running the script.

When I try to post request to it, I receive an error of 404.

Folder structure: (where is the best place to store php files with the current set up I have?)
[image]

Axios request:

```
actions: {
      addUser({ state, commit }){
          axios.post('../public/api/submitUser.php', {
              firstname: state.userInput.firstname
          }).then(function (response) {
              console.log(response);
          }).catch((response) => {
              console.log(response);
              let errorobject = response.response.data.errors;
              for (let key in errorobject) {
                  if (errorobject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                      console.log(errorobject[key]);
                      this.backenderror = errorobject[key];
                  }
              }
          })
      }
  }
```

Error:
[image: error]

Comment: Your web server isn't set up properly with the PHP interpreter then.

Comment: You need to verify how is your project folder structure within your server (apache or whatever) add that information in your question. At first look it seems something  related with the path since you are posting to `../public/api/submitUser.php` and the error states `.../api...` without public

Comment: @JorgeCampos yeah that was an outdated screenshot, sorry, updated it now. I am currently running everything locally and running the command `npm run serve`

Comment: @Devon Can you elaborate how it might not be set up correctly?

Comment: Aaahh, @Devon is right then. PHP is an interpreted language, which means that you need to run your project in a server (container) that supports it. There are ways to run it through node/npm, but, you really shouldn't. Read this article: https://medium.com/@MartinMouritzen/how-to-run-php-in-node-js-and-why-you-probably-shouldnt-do-that-fb12abe955b0 it may help you out

Comment: @JorgeCampos ok so if I shouldn't use node/npm then how should I run my vue project, so that php is "in a server"? Or is it not possible to combine vue and php in this way?

Comment: @Otto Well, if you want your backend to be in PHP, you need to setup a webserver to serve files from your folder ..../public/api/ to some publicaly accessable URL like domain.com/api/submitUser.php. You can then make requests with axios to this URL.

Comment: @Otto To your other question - you need some way to interpret php files and serve them, although it is possible to interpret php files with node, it is not recomended and I would advise to use some webserver with well established support for PHP like Apache. We are using an Apache on our production servers to serve both php back-end and vue front-end build with webpack so we don't need to run node at all.